# Altium - How to place partly off PCB

Tags: altium

I am just starting to use Altium to layout a PCB. I have made my own parts with 3D models. I have to large parts - one an LCD module, and the other a STM32F303RE Nucleo-64 dev board. I made an outline of them on the footprint, using the Top Overlay layer, so that I can know where the board will sit and I won't place anything beneath it that will interfere. The LCD and dev board will sit on top, using headers.

When I go to move the parts partly off the board (with all the pins still on the PCB, it automatically moves it back, entirely into the PCB area. Physically, there are only headers on the one side of the dev board and LCD module, the rest could hang over the PCB edge.

I have tried removing mechanical outlines, and changing the top overlay to dimensions layer, but it still won't let me place the part over the PCB edge.

If anyone can suggest a solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, with a little experimentation, that it was the Origin that was preventing parts from being over the PCB edge. Apparently parts can't be placed in 'negative' space.

Comment: That's why I always use a relative origin, and put my board far away from the absolute origin